# ClickHouse doesn't synchronize new table from MySQL

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

I am using ClickHouse with MySQL Replication by the below command.

```
CREATE DATABASE ExampleDb ENGINE = MaterializeMySQL('mysql:3306', 'db', 'admin', 'password');
```

It works wells for inserting and updating data on the existing tables. However, if I delete or create a new table on ExampleDb, it will not synchronize. I need to drop the database and create a new one in ClickHouse.

Is there any way to solve the above problem?

Comment: could you check log */var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log* and provide the related records?

Comment: CH tests cover this case - see https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/tests/integration/test_materialize_mysql_database/materialize_with_ddl.py#L140. It should work.